# How do I put a link inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text that I want to change into a link using javascript.
I've already figured out the textchanger fuction with a button but then when I put the link in my script section it doesn't recognize it.
The link is not a domain but just another html page.
Ever so thank you for the help!
Greetings.

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245062/6634591)

Answer (score 0):

What about using normal `<a>` tag? Or if you are trying to open a link after button click for example, check this http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You don't need jQuery, especially not, if you don't even know how to generate links

Answer (score 0):

You can use the temple string

```js
const link = `<a href="Your LINK HERE">Your TEXT here</a>`
```